# Org: adding category to non-top headers

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I use one unique `diary.org` file for my Org Agenda.

My file is structured as `:tree-type week`, hence is every entry like:

```
* 2019
** 2019-W21
*** 2019-05-26
**** entry
```

I would like to add category to any entry captured to this file, which I could do by editing my `org-capture` template.

However, categories don't show up in Org Agenda unless they're marking a file or a top-level item.

Do you know how to make categories work for non-top headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do the following and it seems to work for headings that are not the top-level:

```
** not a top heading
:PROPERTIES:
:CATEGORY: category_name
:END:

*** TODO this will be in agenda with category_name
```

Comment: That doesn't work here, neither for second level heading nor for third level heading (with `:CATEGORY:` being set in second level heading). I'm expecting to set `:CATEGORY:` at fourth-level heading (and to make it appear in agenda at fourth-level heading). The manual doesn't say much about it but I was somehow thinking this was expected behavior given [this post](https://sachachua.com/blog/2016/12/using-categories-organize-org-agenda/) from Sacha Chua.

Comment: not sure if this matters.... my org mode version 9.1.9 with Emacs 26.3

Comment: it actually does work (I'm on or 9.2.6), still don't understand why it used not to. Thanks anyway.